# Excel 2007: How do I make a formula to automatically remove (partially) duplicate rows of data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, duplicate

I am wanting to automatically delete any rows of data A#:C# which  have duplicate dataset combinations in columns A (alphabetical text) AND B (numeric text) so that every row has a unique combination of datasets within its cells in column A and B.

For instance, in the following example, I would want Excel to automatically delete ONLY row 4 (A4:F4):

[image: excel example]

Comment: Could you sort it first? Would a helper column be an option? You could concatenate the two strings, sort the list and then have a formula compare one cell to the next one and give you 1 or 0. But that's a lot of question marks. :-) A macro would be a lot easier.

Comment: I've added an answer but it assumes you want a row removed if columns A and C match another rows columns A and C.  In your question it is not clear, because you say A and B but your example uses A and C.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to add a 4th column which concatenates columns A and C like this:

```
=$A1&$C1
```

Then copy the formula down.

Then select all 4 columns and click Data --> Remove Duplicates.  Select only column D and there you go.

Edit - I think it is worth pointing out it will delete the latest duplicate, in your example row 6 not 4.

Comment: Hello Pete, Oops! Sorry to confuse: I changed thehe example but didn't adjust my first sentence. SHould have read:

Comment: Hello Pete, Oops! Sorry to confuse: I changed thehe example but didn't adjust my first sentence. I actually meant to compare A and B among rows in the example, which was why I noted I'd want 4 to be removed (because it's cells A4 and B4 match A2 and B2). But I get what you mean.  Thank you, but I realized as I went to Data that I can simply select all columns & rows, click on Data and select only columns A and C, and that takes care of my duplicate rows. Sorry for asking what must seem like an obvious question, but Pete your answer got me to what I needed!  Thank TheUser1024 for your input.